# CSS Applying wildcard to pseudo classes

Tags: css, wildcard, pseudo-class

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question but I can't seem to work out how to do this. Can you apply a wildcard to an anchor hover/focus so that the style is applied to all classes?

Something like

```
a:hover * { color: #ff0000; }
```

Say I have

```
a { color: #DD0000; }
a.link { color: #ffffff; }
a.link2 { color: #000000; }
a.user { ...
a.anything { ...
```

The easiest way to explain what I'm looking for is to have a global :hover style, but multiple :link styles.
Thanks

Comment: `a:hover { color: #ff0000; }` isn't what you are looking for ?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be overriding the a classes. there is no change on hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this. As mentioned by others, you can apply the same style to multiple classes like so:

```
div a.class1:hover, div a.class2:hover, div a.class3:hover { ... }
```

You can also create a custom class just for the style you want to apply:

```
div a.customClass:hover { ... }
```

You could use `*` like you mentioned in the question, but [apply hover to it](http://jsfiddle.net/2thEu/):

```
div *:hover { ... }
```

There's also this option, where you just apply the style for all `a`'s, although you probably know about this option already:

```
a:hover { ... }
```

**Edit:** If your style is being "overwritten" by something else, a quick and easy way to check would be to use your browser's developer tools to inspect the element. You can even apply pseudo-classes (ie. apply `:hover` pseudo-class even when you're not hovering over the element) with the developer tools included with Chrome and Firefox (you may need to download Firebug to do this with Firefox).

Another option would be to use `!important` to increase the selector's specificity. For example:

```
a:hover { background: red !important; }
```

You can read more about how the specificity is calculated [here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: @Conner a:hover ... doesn't seem to be working. I have added an extra line to my original post. I have defined a { ... } to set all links 1 colour. I want to change the colour of various links a.link {} but the hover to be the same for everyone one. I know a:hover should work but the additional classes seem to be overriding so there is no change upon hover

Comment: @leejmurphy, an easy way of checking where the style being applied is coming from is to inspect the element with your browser's developer tool. If your desired style is being overwritten by something else, a shortcut to increasing its specificity value would be to use `!important`. I've updated my answer with more details on how to do this.

Comment: yes the first thing i tried was chrome's developer tool. As i've mentioned in another comment, the actual class defined is overriding the hover, e.g. a.something { color: ... } is overriding a:hover { ... }

Comment: @leejmurphy, have you tried using `!important` ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2yPm/))? This seems to be more an issue of selector specificity than finding the right "global selector". In general, less specific selectors will be overwritten by more specific selectors, so any global `:hover` pseudo-class will be overwritten by a class selector anyway. If `!important` does not work for you, and if you cannot change how your styles cascade, then you might have to bite the bullet and just list all the classes (or create a separate class for it).

Comment: Yes I did try `!important` which does work, however I try to avoid using it as it isn't best practice. I've combined @menislici 's approach and added 1 single class which will override, e.g. 
`a.hover.link {}` and `a.hover.something {}` will be overridden by `a.hover:hover {}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a global css rule for a specific tag, write (for anchors):

```
a:link{/*your styles go here*/}
a:hover{/*your styles go here*/}
a:active{/*your styles go here*/}
a:visited{/*your styles go here*/}
```

If you would like a special link styled in a different way (maybe making it a button), just apply a class to it and style the class:

```
a.customlink{/*your styles go here*/}
```

EDIT: if you want only some properties of the link to change on hover, which are going to be the same for two different links (let's say one ha yellow, while the other red colored background, and you wanted them both to have a black background), add another same class to the two links, and stylize it.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cye4X/)

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to solve it by adding a common class to all elements as you suggested. This then overrides the default style. Seems to be the most efficient way I've come across so far without using !important

Answer (score 0):

You could separate them by commas like `a:hover link, a:hover link2, a:hover etc { color: #ff0000; }`

Does `a:hover { color: #ff0000; }` not do what you want it to?

Comment: I wanted to avoid writing a statement for each one (i know I can comma separate) because a) there may be quite a few different styles and b) i think it seems unnecessary if it can be done with a global declaration. a:hover doesn't seem to be overriding the additional styles. Is it because I have defined a { ... } ?